# Cannot infer instance using evaluator

Tags: haskell, type-inference, hugs

I've started to work through http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/monads for a intro on functional programming course. What better way to try and understand stuff than to actually try and test the code.

Alas, on the second page I encounter the following:

```
data Expr = Val Int | Div Expr Expr

eval            :: Expr -> Int 
eval (Val n)    = n 
eval (Div x y)  = eval x `div` eval y
```

Which produces an error when I try to run it. I'm not quite sure why this happens.
When I try

```
eval (Val 4) `div` eval (Val 2)
```

in the repl-loop, it works just fine, but

```
eval 4 `div` eval 2
```

Ends in a type inference error.

When I update my definition to the following:

```
data Expr = Val Int | Div Expr Expr

eval            :: Expr -> Int 
eval (Val n)    = n 
eval (Div x y)  = eval (Val x) `div` eval (Val y)
```

I get a type error in definition. What is wrong with the first definition?
The course uses Hugs by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `eval` expects is an argument of a type that `eval` is defined for. Looking at the signature, it requires an argument of type `Expr`, either a `Val` or a `Div`. `eval 4` means that you're passing an `Int` to the function. For that to work, `eval` would have to be defined as:

```
eval :: Int -> Int
```

By writing `(Val 4)`, you are invoking one of the data constructors of `Expr` type, creating a new value of type `Expr`, which you can pass to `eval` and make the compiler happy.

Comment: Yeah, I get that much,  but then why doesn't  eval (Div (Val 4) (Val 2)) work or eval (Div (eval Val 4) (eval Val 2)) ?

Comment: @Apeiron I tried `eval (Div (Val 4) (Val 2))` and it works. The result is `2`. `eval (Div (eval Val 4) (eval Val 2))` doesn't work, because `eval Val 4` will result in an `Int` and you cannot use an `Int` in `Div` constructor - you need an `Expr`.